# What's the meaning of xxxxx-1.apk?

Tags: android

I install an apk and its package name is com.qihoo.appstore. Why in the /data/app directory its name is com.qihoo.appstore-2.apk. My question is what is the meaning of "-2" in the last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, any file you download which has the same name as one already available will get a number behind the name it has, which explains why you have that number there.
It can be confusing if you got different versions for each apk and you can't remember which one is the one you want to use.
For fixing it, you either have to delete the older ones that have no number and/or a lower number in the file name, or make a list of what version you gotten for each numbered and non-numbered file.